# Action Filter ActionParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` which I want to accept parameters through but I can't figure out pass them across.

So my action filter looks like this;

```
public class PreventAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Home/Index");
    }
}
```

And I decorate my action like so;

```
[PreventAction]
public ActionResult Ideas()
{
  return View();
}
```

Now I want to add a parameter so I can call the filter like this;

```
[PreventAction(myParam1 = "1", myParam2 = "2")]
public ActionResult Ideas()
{
  return View();
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add `MyParam1` and `MyParam2` as properties of your `PreventAction` class.  If you require the parameters to be there (rather then being optional), add them as arguments to a constructor for `PreventAction` instead.

Here's a [quick tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28VS.71%29.aspx) of a simple attribute class from MSDN.